# Updating TableView Row Colour with Result From MySQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, scenebuilder

My users can create jobs that are added to a MySQL database. The jobs have a priority (1, 2 or 3). What I would like to do is modify the colour of individual rows based on the priority of the job, for example prioirty 3 is a red row as this is a more urgent job, priority 1 is a green row as it has a lower urgency.

I have a job model class that has a getter/setter for priority;

```
    public int getPrioritySetting() {
    return prioritySetting;
    }

public void setPrioritySetting(final int prioritySetting) {
    this.prioritySetting = prioritySetting;
    }
```

I have two questions, what is the "easiest" way to get the priority of each inidivual job from the MySQL database and (using this), what is the "easiest" way to modify the appearance of the row? I'm currently using TableView in JavaFX with FXML files built through scenebuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the first question: presumably you are getting the `Job` objects from the database at some point anyway, so you would just populate the `prioritySetting` field when you do so.

To change the appearance of the row, use a row factory, and set some CSS pseudoclasses

```
PseudoClass highPriority = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("high-priority");
PseudoClass lowPriority = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("low-priority");
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Job>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Job item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(highPriority, item != null && item.getPrioritySetting() == 3);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(lowPriority, item != null && item.getPrioritySetting() == 1);
    }
});
```

Then just define whatever style you need in an external CSS file:

```
.table-row-cell:high-priority {
    -fx-background: red ;
}
.table-row-cell:low-priority {
    -fx-background: green ;
}
```

Here is an SSCCE

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithPriorityRowColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Job> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("Name", Job::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Value", Job::valueProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Priority", Job::priorityProperty));

        PseudoClass highPriority = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("high-priority");
        PseudoClass lowPriority = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("low-priority");
        table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Job>(){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Job job, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(job, empty);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(highPriority, job != null && job.getPriority() == 3);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(lowPriority, job != null && job.getPriority() == 1);
            }
        });

        table.getItems().addAll(createJobs());

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("table-view-with-priority.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public List<Job> createJobs() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 40)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Job("Job "+i, i, rng.nextInt(3) + 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    public static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Job {
        private final StringProperty name  = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty priority = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Job(String name, int value, int priority) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
            setPriority(priority);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty priorityProperty() {
            return this.priority;
        }

        public final int getPriority() {
            return this.priorityProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setPriority(final int priority) {
            this.priorityProperty().set(priority);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the CSS code shown above in the file `table-view-with-priority.css`.

Comment: Would I need to then apply the CSS files to anything or would the PseudoClass pick this up itself?

Comment: You need the external CSS file (just add it to the scene's stylesheets). You could do it with inline CSS but it gets much messier and is a pain to find the code if you want to change the style, so this is much preferable.

Comment: thanks I now have this working perfectly. Just to extend on this a bit, would there be enough space in the comments to explain how I would go about making the text of each cell bold regardless of priority? The colours on the cells are making the text (which is weak already) difficult to read now.

Comment: Add `.table-row-cell { -fx-font-weight: bold ; }` to the css file. (Though I don't actually see a problem when I run it.)